# Apply and keep advanced labeling settings in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, legend

I want to do a map in ArcMap and keep the labeling that I set in the layer properties for the map legend.
Somehow, when i click 'apply' the values of the advanced labeling appear in the legend, but when I click 'OK' afterwards they disappear again and all my settings are lost.

What is wrong?

[image]

EDIT:
Elaborating on @Martin's comment:
I tried to edit the legend entries (and my may be the mistake due to your point!?) via the symbology. I thought this worked, because when I set the interval size in the advanced labeling to 100, click OK in the Advanced labeling window and then Apply ('Übernehmen') in the Layer Properties window, the eight labels from 1000 to 1700 appear at the ticks in the legend. However, as soon as I click OK in the layer properties window, they disappear again and all my settings are lost. Maybe that is the strange thing about it.

Comment: I think the reason you haven't got any answers is that people doesn't understand the question. You talk about labeling (which is related to text strings on your map) and legends, and show images about symbology. Non of which are directly related. Could you be a bit more specific about your problem? What steps are you taking when it occurs?

Comment: What about if you press Apply and then Cancel? Your changes should still be applied.

Comment: I absolutely do not understand why, but that did the job....you may post that as an answer!

Comment: Okay, another comment on that: it stays only as long as you draw the map for the next time then (e.g. if you add/remove another layer...)

Comment: Alright, I'll keep it as a comment then for future readers. Maybe someone else will have a better solution later on! Hopefully it solved your problem at least temporarily.